# Cannot uncheck radiobutton when used inside two linear layout

Tags: android, xml, radio-button, radio-group

I am using two linear layouts to display two rows of radio button 3 in one row and 3 in other row.I have searched and found that we should use `radio group`. But after using radio group also I am not able to uncheck the radio button when I select a radio button

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/payment_mode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            style="@style/LinkButton"
            android:id="@+id/cash"
            android:text="CASH" />

        <RadioButton
            style="@style/LinkButton"
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:text="CARD" />

        <RadioButton
            style="@style/LinkButton"
            android:id="@+id/pay_tm"
            android:text="PAYTM" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            style="@style/LinkButton"
            android:id="@+id/bank"
            android:text="BANK" />

        <RadioButton
            style="@style/LinkButton"
            android:id="@+id/cc_av"
            android:text="CC-AV" />

        <RadioButton
            style="@style/LinkButton"
            android:id="@+id/credit"
            android:text="CREDIT" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 0):

> You can't use any layout inside `RadioGroup`. You can use only
>   `RadioButton`, otherwise `RadioButton` won't work. `RadioButton`
>   should be immediate child of RadioGroup.

Your problem will be solved by changing the orientation of the radioGroup to horizontal.
More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005551/androidplacing-the-radio-buttons-horizontally)

Answer (score 0):

From the developers website

> To create each radio button option, create a RadioButton in your
>   layout. However, because radio buttons are mutually exclusive, you
>   must group them together inside a RadioGroup. By grouping them
>   together, the system ensures that only one radio button can be
>   selected at a time.

So the direct parent of the radio button has to be the RadioGroup , in you layout file the direct parent is the LinearLayout. Remove the LinearLayout and place the radiobuttons directly under the RadioGroup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your layout like this and do on click action refer this [link](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/payment_mode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/cash"
                style="@style/LinkButton"

                android:text="CASH" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/card"
                style="@style/LinkButton"
                android:text="CARD" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/pay_tm"
                style="@style/LinkButton"
                android:text="PAYTM" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/bank"
                style="@style/LinkButton"
                android:text="BANK" />


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/cc_av"
                style="@style/LinkButton"
                android:text="CC-AV" />


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/credit"
                style="@style/LinkButton"
                android:text="CREDIT" />

        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my answer you need not to use the radio group. You just have to set click listener on each radio button. For eg.

```
RadioButton tempRadioButton;   //global variable.
radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (tempRadioButton != null){
                        tempRadioButton.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    tempRadioButton = (RadioButton) view;
                }
            });
```

You can also use this method to set the radio buttons on each item of list view or recyclerview.